# Kafka Streams: Global state store low level processor - process method

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When does the `process` method gets invoked in the low level processor class override (for e.g. `LoadService`)? Wanted to convert the key to upper case while persisting into the state store, but it appears that the `process` method is never invoked.

```java
builder.addGlobalStore(svcBuilder,
    "svcsource",
    Serdes.String().deserializer(), 
    Serdes.String().serializer(),
    "svctopic",
    "loadsvc",
    () -> new LoadService());
```

.

```
public class LoadService implements Processor<String, String> {
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    }

    public void process(String key, String serviceType) {
        System.out.println(key.toUpperCase());
    }

    public void close() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your implementation of `LoadService`?  Note that LoadService must be a `ProcessorSupplier`, not a `Processor` itself.

Comment: Hi Michael,please see above.

Comment: `process()` should be invoked for each input record. Do you consumer the topic from beginning? Also note, that Kafka Streams commits offsets and thus, you cannot just stop and restart to process the same data again, but you would need to reset the application (cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html) -- or you write new data while the application is running.